# Is it possible to access and manipulate the parts of the base topographic map from ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, basemap

I noticed the base topographic map that you start projects with has extensively detailed roads/streams/etc. for my area of interest and it's actually better than what I'm able to find elsewhere. [This is the map in question.](https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer) Does anyone know if there's a way to do one of the following:

- Access/download a broken-up version of this map where I can access the individual vectors
- Break up the topographic map directly to use said vectors
- Find the specific sources they used to create this map

I'm expecting the answer to be "no it's proprietary" but I thought I'd check just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have answered your question...basemaps are more or less static except for change of detail on different zoom levels. In the contents pane you can uncheck references for places but that's it. Welcome to the painful world of thematic mapping, you have to find shape files, query and change symbology to your taste. Build a data repository for this if this is a common task you are doing.